# WCFの接続エラーから原因を特定する方法

Tags: c#, wcf

.NET Framework 4.5でWCFサービスと、それを利用するクライアントアプリケーションを作っています。
WCFサービスの引数や戻り値に使用するカスタムクラスや列挙型で、`DataMember`属性とか`EnumMember`属性を付け忘れることがあるのですが、このときにクライアント側で発生する例外のメッセージから原因を特定するのが難しく困っています。
戻り値がカスタムクラスで、そのいずれかのプロパティで使用している`enum`のメンバーに`EnumMember`属性を付け忘れると、次のようなエラーが出ます。

Exceptionの型：`System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException`
メッセージ：`基礎になる接続が閉じられました: 維持される必要があった接続が、サーバーによって切断されました`
※実際には`TargetInvocationException`が発生しており、その`InnerException`に上記の`CommunicationException`が入っていた。

このメッセージから、データコントラクト周りの属性付け忘れの可能性があることまでは、経験として覚えました。
しかし、どこで何を付け忘れているのかという具体的な原因は、今のところひたすらコードを目視で精査している状況です。
もう少しデバッグをしやすくする手段はないものでしょうか？

例外をToStringした結果を記載しておきます。
`System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: 呼び出しのターゲットが例外をスローしました。 ---> System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: 基礎になる接続が閉じられました: 維持される必要があった接続が、サーバーによって切断されました ---> System.Net.WebException: 基礎になる接続が閉じられました: 維持される必要があった接続が、サーバーによって切断されました ---> System.IO.IOException: 転送接続からデータを読み取れません: 既存の接続はリモート ホストに強制的に切断されました。。 ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: 既存の接続はリモート ホストに強制的に切断されました。`
※以下スタックトレースは省略

Answer (score 1):

`[EnumMember]`の場合`CommunicationException`ではなく内部例外のエラーメッセージを見ればフィールド名も含めて原因が分かるはずです。
`excetion.ToString()`をログに出力するなどしておけばよいかと。

Comment: すみません、該当する情報を見つけられません。`InnerException`をたどると、順に`CommunicationException`→WebException`→IOException`→SocketException`→`null`となりますが、どこに入っていますか？　ToString()の結果は本文に追記しておきます。

Comment: @mok2pok クライアント側の話ですよね？クライアントの認識していないエラーはサーバーがエラー情報を通知する気がなければ情報は得られません。サーバー側のログを確認するか、[serviceDebug](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/ms788993%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)などを設定してみてはいかがでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

データコントラクタをチェックするコード書いてみました。
実行時のログで調査するのも良いですが、事前に保証できるようにして置くのも
一つの方法だと思います。
単体テストでデータコントラクタを事前にチェックしておくのが良いと思いますが、
私の場合は、デバッグ実行時のみチェックが走るようにしたりしています。
ご参考まで。

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

namespace Tests
{
#if DEBUG

    // テスト用にenumを宣言
    [DataContract]
    public enum MyEnum
    {
        [EnumMember]
        Enum1,

        [EnumMember]
        Enum2,

        // これがエラー
        Enum3,
    }

    // テスト用にデータコントラクタを宣言
    [DataContract]
    public class MyData
    {
        [DataMember]
        public MyEnum MyEnum { get; set; }
    }

    // データコントラクタをチェックするクラスです
    public static class DataContractChecker
    {
        // データコントラクタをインスタンスからチェックする
        // デバッグ実行時のチェックはこっちを使うと楽かもです。
        public static void Assert(object dataContract)
        {
            Debug.Assert(dataContract != null);
            Assert(dataContract.GetType());
        }

        // タイプからチェックする。
        // ユニットテストなどはこっちの方が楽かな。
        public static void Assert(Type dataContractType)
        {
            // [DataContract]属性が指定されている
            Debug.Assert(dataContractType.CustomAttributes.Any(atr => atr.AttributeType == typeof (DataContractAttribute)),
                string.Format("class {0} に DataContract属性が必要です", dataContractType.FullName));

            // [DataMember]が付いているプロパティを列挙し、そのプロパティがenumのものに絞る
            var q = dataContractType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
                .Where(p => p.CustomAttributes.Any(atr => atr.AttributeType == typeof (DataMemberAttribute)))
                .Where(p => p.PropertyType.IsEnum)
                .Select(p => p.PropertyType);

            foreach (var et in q)
            {
                // enumにも[DataContract]属性が指定されている
                Debug.Assert(et.CustomAttributes.Any(atr => atr.AttributeType == typeof (DataContractAttribute)),
                    string.Format("enum {0} に DataContractAttribute属性が必要です", et.FullName));

                foreach (var ev in et.GetEnumValues())
                {
                    var en = ev.GetType().GetField(ev.ToString());

                    // enumの列挙子に[EnumMember]属性がしていされている
                    Debug.Assert(en.GetCustomAttributes(typeof (EnumMemberAttribute), false).Length == 1,
                        string.Format("enum {0} / {1} に EnumMember属性が必要です", et.FullName, en.Name));
                }
            }
        }

        // 呼び出し方のサンプルです。
        public static void Test()
        {
            Assert(typeof (MyData));
            Assert(new MyData());
        }
    }
#endif
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`wcf`のトレースログを出力するようにconfigファイルを変更し、出力されたログを下記のツールから閲覧すると、より詳しく調べることができるかもしれません。

トレースログ出力の設定方法などは以下のMSDNページに記載があります。

cf. [Service Trace Viewer Tool (SvcTraceViewer.exe)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732023%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)